# bash while loop with mixed condition

Tags: bash, while-loop, conditional-statements

I'm not meaning multiple conditions, well it's also but mixed from that:

```
while [[ read line ] && [ "$GoodURL" == "false" ]]
```

What is the correct form for that? It's a while loop that runs on a text file line by line,
and I want to stop it with that `$GoodURL` type of boolean, please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while read line && [[ "$GoodURL" == "false" ]]
do 
    echo $line; 
done
```

In case you want to read from a file/pipe, be sure to use indirection or you will get funny results (due the while loop executing in a subshell and not actually using the same environmen as the surrounding shell)

```
while read line && [[ "$GoodURL" == "false" ]]
do 
    echo $line; 
done < input.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't work if I check if a process is still running. For example, `while read LINE && [[ pgrep "gnote" > /dev/null ]]` fails. `pgrep gedit` checks if a application is still running.` Is there any other way I can make it work

Comment: Ah . Sorry. `while read LINE && pgrep "gnote" > /dev/null`. This fails as well.

Comment: @KhurshidAlam Works like a charm for me. Of course, `pgrep` runs /after/ read and and exiting `gnote` does not interrupt that. You need to ask your own question.